How do I override the .gitconfig [merge] ff=only setting in VS Code?
I prefer to have git do only fast-forward merges automatically, so I have included a
[merge]
    ff = only

stanza in my .gitconfig file. When I do need to do a more complex merge, I want to do use VS Code as a three-way merge tool. Alas, when I try to do that, the ff = only setting prevents the merge from running in VS Code.
I'm hoping that there is a better option than editing the .gitconfig file every time I want to do a non-FF merge in VS Code. There is a way around this in PyCharm.

How do you start the merge? With git commands, use git -c merge.ff=false merge or git -c merge.ff=false pull origin foo to override merge.ff=only for this command. If you use GUI buttons, I'm afraid there's no chance to customize the option unless the menu provides some widgets.

Is there a way to start a merge inside VS Code where I can specify a full command? I only know how to do this from a menu.

@bht ... the integrated terminal?
